# Formatting a column as a currency

Tags: exceljs

I am using the exceljs library in nodejs to read in an xlsx file, update some fields, apply some formatting, and save as a new file.

I am trying to apply a currency format to a column

`worksheet1.getColumn(6).numFmt = '#,##0.00 [$€-1];[Red]-#,##0.00 [$€-1]';`

This applies the format to column 6 as expected, but also to ALL other blank cells in the document.

This is surely not correct!

Any ideas?

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Just tried to use the same with latest exceljs version in my angular project and it works as expected. Blank cells remain as it is.

Are you sure you are not adding blank strings or some whitespace data into all excels by mistake?

Or you meant something else by "ALL other blank cells.."?